# Why am I getting "danger of being blocked" message?

Tags: support, questions

I wanted to post a question, but the page shows:

[image]

Looking back, I only see two questions asked, both with positive upvotes.

Why am I getting this message?

Answer (score 2):

In the past your questions were very brief and were closed due to lack of research undertaken before being asked or were migrated to other stack exchange sites (where they were often closed off too for the same reason).

That was a while ago though so provided you stick to the guidance outlined in the [HELP](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) section you should be OK. But if more questions are badly received and closed / deleted then that risks you being prevented from asking more questions in the future.

Comment: Which questions were they, How do I refer to those questions?

Comment: @Pacerier  You have three deleted questions as well. One received 5 downvotes before it was closed and deleted here. The other two were migrated - one to English.SE (which has also since been deleted) and the other to [webapps here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19254/does-google-change-ctrl-to-cmd-if-you-are-using-mac) which has also been closed but not deleted as it received an upvoted answer. All these three questions were your most recent ones, and all of equally low quality, hence the resulting closure and deletion.

Comment: How do I gain access to the two questions you were talking about?